# Elasticsearch groovy script loading error

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have just installed elasticsearch 2.4.3 on our new ubuntu servers. while starting server I got this error.

```
2016-12-22 20:22:56,199][INFO ][script                   ] [frrole-esprod-data-2-vm4] compiling script file [/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/userintel_updates.groovy]
[2016-12-22 20:22:56,201][WARN ][script                   ] [frrole-esprod-data-2-vm4] failed to load/compile script [userintel_updates]
ScriptException[Error compiling script 5fe76475eb1c3c852696768a11f91509af4f6564]; nested: MultipleCompilationErrorsException[startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation specified at jar:file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/lang-groovy/groovy-2.4.6-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation

Could not instantiate global transform class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation specified at jar:file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/lang-groovy/groovy-2.4.6-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation

2 errors
];
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$2.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$2.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:145)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService.compile(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService$ScriptChangesListener.onFileInit(ScriptService.java:543)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.onFileCreated(FileWatcher.java:256)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.init(FileWatcher.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.createChild(FileWatcher.java:173)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.listChildren(FileWatcher.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.onDirectoryCreated(FileWatcher.java:299)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.init(FileWatcher.java:162)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher$FileObserver.access$000(FileWatcher.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.FileWatcher.doInit(FileWatcher.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.AbstractResourceWatcher.init(AbstractResourceWatcher.java:36)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService.add(ResourceWatcherService.java:133)
    at org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService.add(ResourceWatcherService.java:126)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.<init>(ScriptService.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleMethodInjector.inject(SingleMethodInjector.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:95)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:823)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:818)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:823)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:818)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$ProviderImpl.get(ProviderLookup.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$1.get(MapBinder.java:323)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.MapBinder$RealMapBinder$1.get(MapBinder.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:823)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:818)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.get(Multibinder.java:195)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:201)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:46)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:213)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:194)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:45)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation specified at jar:file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/lang-groovy/groovy-2.4.6-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation

Could not instantiate global transform class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation specified at jar:file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/lang-groovy/groovy-2.4.6-indy.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ProcessingUnit.completePhase(ProcessingUnit.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ProcessingUnit.gotoPhase(ProcessingUnit.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:536)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngineService$2.run(GroovyScriptEngineService.java:159)
    ... 182 more
```

Scripts are perfectly working on our other cluster which is running elasticsearch 2.4.0.
Any idea why this might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible, that you are importing special classes in your scripts, that are not supported and need to be whitelisted? See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting-security.html

You could try disabling the security manager and see what happens (even though you should turn it on in production!) as a first try.